# Changing default user for PostgreSQL on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, postgresql

I just installed PostgreSQL 13 on Windows 10. In the command prompt I did:

```
C:\Users\Max>cd ../postgres
```

I then tried to do the `createdb` command and got this error message:

```
createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Max"
```

After some research I know that if I don’t specify a database user with `-U username` option, it takes the OS username.

When I cd into the `postgres` user, why does it still use the user `"Max"`?
Is there a way I can change it to authenticate as `postgres` when I'm in `C:\Users\Max` so I don't have to specify the username every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind I found the answer.

- Right click on Windows icon and click “System”
- Scroll down to “Advanced System Settings”
- Click Environment Variables
- In “System variables”, click “New”:

  Variable Name: `PGUSER`

  Variable Value: `postgres`

Comment: For anyone wondering, you may have to close and reopen your existing terminal session for the environment variable to take effect. Alternatively, you could run `set PGUSER=postgres` to also set it for the existing session. Then as long as you have set the environment variable in the instructions above, subsequent sessions should already have it set.

Comment: Thank you, really :)